# What are practical differences between 8-max and 9-max tournaments?

Tags: poker-theory

Most online poker sites offer specialized tournaments with 8 players vs 9 players on a table, and some people have been advocating 8-max for live games as well.

For 6 max, the difference is pretty clear - there's much more action due to the need to pay for blinds more often, and hands are played faster in general since there are only 6 players. The same goes for 6-max -> 4 max and 4 max -> heads up. At each step, the resulting play varies significantly.

Superficially however, the difference between 8-max and 9-max seems to be pretty small. Am I missing something significant here?

Comment: To me, 8-max tourneys are just 9-max tourneys without an UTG player; meaning no difference at all. I don't know why they offer 8-max tourneys to say the truth, unless there are heavy changes in blind structure or timings.

Comment: Why without UTG? There will always be a player to act first on the left of the BB.

Comment: @disco beat, i actually meant one player less to act in early position, since there are 2 _universally accepted_ early positions as UTG and UTG+1, one missing is no big deal. Of course there is always an UTG player ;) but one missing is way different than, say, 3 missing as _6-max_

Comment: @vlzvl It's strange how we all see things differently. I would say that there will be 1 less middle position player to act :)

Comment: @disco beat, frankly i never thought about that but i'm pretty sure the positions are _reduced_ from earlier ones ;) There will be always blinds, a button and/or a cut off. Quoting [Harrington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Harrington), a 6-max is effectively a 9-max with all EP folded ;) It's easier to say that rather removing 3 middle players, due to more significance of an EP player rather an MP player  ;)

Comment: @vlzvl As late position are most important than early ones, I can totally understand this point.

Comment: Agreed with vlzvl here. The number of players after you matters more than the number of players before you, so having one less player mostly impacts early positions and can be treated as if the UTG is gone.

Comment: I agree with others that there shouldn't be much of a difference, but one thing to keep in mind is that the difference is a little more pronounced in late stages of the tourney when tables aren't always full.  At that point you might be playing 6 or 7 handed, and when it's down to 9 people you'd actually be 4 and 5 handed for a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you remove players from a table, the same rules apply.

More blinds to pay turn into more action.
Less cards distributed turn into the average starting hand being lowered.

Of course, removing 1 player will not change the game as removing 3, but it is good to keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

More players typically means you play fewer hands, within a stronger range, from most or all positions.

Opening UTG with 9 players is going to be perceived as much stronger than doing the same with just 6 players, even though in both cases you are first to act preflop.... Since you have 8 more players to act, rather than 5, you have a much bigger chance of getting 3-bet.

The same is true with a 7- or 8-handed table, just a little less so.

So it’s better to identify positions backward from the button, rather than forward from the big blind, when constructing ranges etc.

Regarding one of the first comments: I would be all in favor of making hold ’em an 8-max game. The idea of 9- or even 10-handed games is a relatively new thing. It seems more driven by casinos wanting to pack in as many people as possible than good play. (No one played 9- or 10-handed when 7-card stud was the dominant game, for obvious reasons.)

To me, 9- or 10-handed games are less appealing, in that it allows players to sit back and wait for premiums and not have to deal with more ambiguous/tricky decisions. Limiting hold ’em to 7 or 8 players means a little more action, a bit more variety, and should requires some more skill, IMHO.